# How can I delete chars from a string from point X to the beginning

Tags: c#, string

I have a string of source code HTML.

So I would go:

```
int X = find indexof("theterm");
thesourcecode = thesourcecode.Substring(????
```

How can I delete all chars from the point where **theterm** is found BEHIND? Thanks SO.

**Edit: An example so people dont' get confused.**

Sample string: "The big red house is so enormous!"

int Position = sampleString.IndexOf("house");

(*pseudocode*) From point Position, and back, delete everything:

Result string after my method: "**is so enourmous!**

Comment: This question is a little confusing, rewording would be highly advised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// this could be set explicitly or variable based on user input.  
   string mySearchString = "TextToFind";
```

THe code below assumes that this will change, otherwise I would have used the number 10 instead of `mySearchString.Length`.

```
int foundIndex = myString.IndexOf(mySearchString);
```

Once you've found the index it's easy:

Remove all the text before your string

```
myString = myString.SubString(0, foundIndex);
```

or remove all the text after your search text.

```
myString = myString.SubString(foundIndex + mySearchString.Length, myString.Length - 1);
```

Comment: xD I can't believe it was that simple. Thanks bro.

Comment: You don't need the second parameter in substring in your second example. The default when using one parameter is till the end of the string.

Comment: Your example seems a little confusing. Shouldn't "remove" be replaced by "getting"? Or "before" and "after" be swapped and the indeces be adjusted?

Comment: @BFree - thanks.  That makes sense.  I think I put it in there out of habit.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean removing all characters preceding a character, you would do:

```
string s = "i am theterm";
int index = s.IndexOf("theterm");
s = s.Substring(index, s.Length - index);
```

Answer (score 0):

You would simply write

```
thesourcecode = thesourcecode.Substring(X);
```

For instance if we did the following:

```
string s = "Hello there everybody!";
s = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("the"));
```

s would now equal "there everybody!"

Answer (score 0):

```
thesourcecode = thesourcecode.Remove(0, thesourcecode.IndexOf("theterm"));
```

Comment: You would have to add the length of the searched text as well.

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
var index = thesourcecode.IndexOf("theterm");
thesourcecode = thesourcecode.Substring(index);
```